# Keep the image ratio while giving a height in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, height

Im trying to give a 500px height to the  of Next js while keeping the ratio of the image. I havent found any way to do so.

```html
   <div className='relative text-center'>
        <Image
          layout="fixed"
          objectFit={'contain'}
          loading="lazy"
          src={image.url}
          alt={image.name}
          width={500}
          height={500}
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: If it works like in HTML/CSS, it will keep ratio of the image if you only specify either height or width.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Thats the problem, it gives an error if just one is specified.

Answer (score 1):

you need to fix the height of the parent while the Image component as cover, for more info check the `next/image` [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#layout)

```
<div className='relative text-center h-96'>
    <Image
       layout="fill"
       objectFit="contain"
       src={image.url}
       alt={image.name}
   />
</div>
```

about 500px you can define custom height on `tailwind.config.js` more info on [doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the full Image isnt shown.

Comment: @AminDarian in this case we can use `contain` instead of `cover`, I edited the answer

Comment: Did that as well, now the height of the image wont be 500px if for instance the width is 900px.

Comment: you can define heights as the tailwindcss doc says on the div